# What characters in text will cause "input string not in a correct format"

Tags: c#

Excuse me if this has been answered I've searched and searched and haven't found the answer.

In c# VS2010 have an array of text boxes

```
TextBox[] txtDescription = new TextBox[32];
```

When assigning a value to this textbox I'm occasionally getting input string not in a correct format.

```
txtDescription[1].Text = m_Objects[1].Description;
```

Because m_Object is reading a file over udp from another computer, it sometimes gets a bad read.  I want to check for these "illegal" characters that are causing the exception and do the read again but for the life of me I can't find out which characters aren't allowed in a textbox.

Is it control characters?  Or a subset of these or others?

I suppose I could create a small program and loop through all the possibilities and note which can't be used but...

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the textbox...

Comment: Are you completely sure exception is coming from this code? The error seem to be related to `String.Format` call...

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure there aren't any characters a TextBox can't handle (but that's not to say you can see them all).

**To investigate:**

I presume this line is causing the exception in your program :

`txtDescription[1].Text = m_Objects[1].Description;`?

When it does, what is the contents of `m_Objects[1].Description`? If you didn't know, you can find this out by hovering over the variable when the exception occurs and the debugger kicks in on that line.

Is it possible that `m_Objects[1].Description` might sometimes be `null`? (also it is unlikely as you would see different exception).

Comment: Sorry Alex, not doing very well here am I :(

Comment: +1 Just either be confident in your answer or don't answer. (I've moved last remaining suggestion to the end).

Answer (score 0):

History has taught us that when we need to check for something to be "in a correct format" for some other piece of software, trying to get an exact and accurate test tends to be pointless. This has happened with SQL injections for example, where the final solution was to give up on putting together a command directly from fragments of SQL and the user's input, but instead to treat those differently.

So instead of trying to check the string (risking that your check doesn't exactly catch all the possible errors), what I'd recommend is that you put a "try/catch" around the code that does the actual checking. If it fails, then you know that you have  to ask for that string again over the network.

An alternative approach would be to use CRC or some other form of error detection/correction to make sure that the data received over the network correctly matches what was sent. Or use TCP, if that's an option.